# R Create multiple graphs with different title and axis names with subscripts and superscript

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

I've spent hours searching and trying to find a way to use expression or bquote to come up with a way to create a new title for each graph I make.  The problem I have is that the title name changes for each graph and there is a different number of subscripts and superscripts in each name.  How do I format my "main=" statement to change to the new title name with the various subscripts and superscripts that I want?

```
# This is the format I want to show on the graphs
# Title Graph1 = "Total pH"  (no super or subscripts)
# Title Graph2 = "Total NO3-"  where "3" subscript and "-" superscript
# Title Graph3 = "Total H2PO3-" where "2" subscript, "3" subscript, and "-" superscript
# Title Graph4 = "Total K+" where "+" is superscript

n <- c("pH", "NO3-", "H2PO3-", "K+")

for (j in n) {
    dev.new(width=10, height = 10)
    plot (x=2,y=3, main=j)
}
```

Comment: I should add, I'm looking to do this for the axis labels as well as the main which is why I added the tag axis-labels.  I assume if there is a solution the same process will work for both plot functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use the `expression` with the `plotmath` notation to create a vector of desired expressions and then sequence through them.

```
n<-expression(pH, NO['3']^'-', H[2]~PO[3]^'-', K^'+')
for (j in n) {
  dev.new(width=10, height = 10)
  plot (x=2,y=3, main=j )
}
```

[image]

See `?plotmath` for the syntax of the notation.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried every combination I could think of except using the "<-" assignment instead of an "=" to do this.  Just started using R last week so sharp learning curve

Answer (score 1):

I threw another wrinkle into this problem.  I also wanted to have different text put into the title name as well as adding the subscripts.  I finally got it to work with the "bquote" command.  Just adding this code example in case someone else runs into this type of problem and is looking for a solution.

```
# This is the format I want to show on the graphs
# Title Graph1 = "Houston - pH"  (no super or subscripts)
# Title Graph2 = "Los Angeles - (NO3-)"  where "3" subscript and "-" superscript
# Title Graph3 = "New York - (H2PO3-)" where "2" subscript, "3" subscript, and "-" superscript
# Title Graph4 = "Omahaa - (K+)" where "+" is superscript

SampleName <- c("Houston", "Los Angeles", "New York", "Omaha")

for (j in 1:4) {
    if (j==1) {
        n <-as.expression(bquote(.(SampleName[j])~'(pH)'))
    } else if (j==2) {
        n <-as.expression(bquote(.(SampleName[j])~'(NO'['3']^'-'*')'))
    } else if (j==3) {
        n <-as.expression(bquote(.(SampleName[j])~'(H'['2']*'PO'['3']^'-'*')'))
    } else {
        n <-as.expression(bquote(.(SampleName[j])~'(K'^'+'*')'))
    }
  dev.new(width=10, height = 10)
  plot (x=2,y=3, main=n )
}
```